# What is the default "global connection" for mssql?

Tags: node.js, npm

In https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#request, there is the following:

---

[image]

---

What is the default global connection that is mentioned?

My app.js contains:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var connectionString = {
  user: ...
  password: ...
  server: ...
}

var sqlConnection = sql.connect(connectionString, function (err) {
     ...
}
```

Separately, I have a data.js which contains:

```
var data = module.exports = {};
var sql = require('mssql');
data.Test = function (callback) {
  new sql.Request().query('select top 1 * from Users'), function (err, rows) {
    callback(err, rows);
    });
}
```

In data.js, I did not make any connection, but the `Test` function returns a successful query from the database connected in app.js. I am puzzled how the code in data.js knows about the global connection? What happens if there were more than one connection?

The only "linkage" I have between the two files is app.js `require` some other module and that module `require` data.js.

Comment: Isn't that the one that is used to connect to the db in the first place ?

Comment: I connected to the db in my app.js.  Then in another module where I keep my data methods, I just had `var sql = require('mssql')` and did a `new Sql.Request()`, and my query worked! How did this module file know what the connection is or that it is already connected?

Comment: Once you install mssql using npm. There's 1 config file mssql.json . There's state the global connection

Comment: How do you install it? using npm. Is it local or remote mssql.

Comment: I installed via npm in Visual Studio, basically with `-s`.

Comment: the very same page you link to shows what it is. It is the connection you've *already* setup. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#quick-example shows up using the global connection, if you need a specific, different, one then you read https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection, build one, and pass that in. This is not a question so much has having forgotten to read the rest of the README.md O_o

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have expanded my question to explain the issue I am facing.

Comment: does your app.js connect first?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the app.js code block in the question.

Comment: you only show two files, not your full app run path, so I (and others) can't tell whether you hit app.js first, or hit data.js first. Your app.js also doesn't show anything that hints at data.js being required at which point in time, so that's not helping. Without a [mcve] I'm going to assume that sql connections are persistent, so the first one that gets set up in `app.js` becomes the global connection. That is, of course, a guess, but requires are cached, so require('mssql') in any file gets *the same* object to work with. It stands to reason that that single object tracks connections.

Comment: On an open source point: this is a great question to ask clarification on over on the mssql repository issue tracker, to ask whether an explanation for this can be explicitly added to the README.md, so that the answer won't just benefit you, but everyone else using this package.